# Easy and Simple way of Implementing ASP.Net Dynamic Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authorization

I am working on my UserManagement module where you can control and assign what a user can see and do, where do I start? I just started MVC and still learning. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Although this is an opinion based question and board to answer, you can see/use `ActionFilterAttribute` or `AuthorizeAttribute` to user access control dynamically.

Comment: As side note, if you are starting then I suggest you rather start with asp.net core. That has more advanced options to implement authorization.